# How to avoid calculation mistakes with primitives

Tags: java, primitive

The following routine is expected to return **1**, but instead it returns **0.9999999999999999**.

```
double sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    sum+=0.1;
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

The same mistake occurs also with other java mathematical operations.

Is there any way to avoid this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not a mistake. It is the nature of floating point operations.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is inherently inaccurate. You could try with ```BigDecimal``` but that's a lot slower.

Comment: I suppose you could round it, if you only need integers

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's called a floating point error.  It is natural and to be expected.  The way to avoid it is to use variables having higher precision, such as `BigDecimal`.  However `BigDecimal` is slower to perform calculations, so consider how important accuracy is important in your solution.

I'd recommend using `BigDecimal` despite any performance hits if these quantities represent currency.  Its more important your calculation be correct than fast in that case.